# Display tooltip on Label's hover?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I have below HTML code ?

```
<label for="male">Hello This Will Have Some Value</label>
```

But actually i dont have enough space to show this much long label. So i thought of creating label as below..

```
<label for="male">Hello...</label>
```

Then i create a hidden field which will hold entire label value

```
<input type="hidden" name="Language" value="Hello This Will Have Some Value">
```

Now when user hovers mouse on `Hello...` can i show hidden field's value `Hello This Will Have Some Value` in tooltip using jquery?

Thanks!

Answer (score 75, accepted):

You can use the **"title attribute"** for label tag.

```
<label title="Hello This Will Have Some Value">Hello...</label>
```

**If you need more control over the looks,**

1 . try http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#tooltips as shown below. But you will need to include bootstrap.

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hello This Will Have Some Value">Hello...</button>
```

2 .  try https://jqueryui.com/tooltip/. But you will need to include jQueryUI.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$(this).tooltip();
});
</script>
```

Comment: Sanchit, i usually get the label value using jquery ajax call. So, can i set title value dynamically?

Comment: Yes, on callback use something like this. 

**$('label').attr('title', VARIABLE_NAME);**

Answer (score 6):

You don't have to use hidden field. Use "title" property. It will show browser default tooltip. You can then  use jQuery plugin (like before mentioned bootstrap tooltip) to show custom formatted tooltip.

```
<label for="male" title="Hello This Will Have Some Value">Hello ...</label>
```

Hint: you can also use css to trim text, that does not fit into the box (text-overflow property). See http://jsfiddle.net/8eeHs/

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `title` attribute in html :)

```
<label title="This is the full title of the label">This is the...</label>
```

When you keep the mouse over for a brief moment, it should pop up with a box, containing the full title.

If you want more control, I suggest you look into the Tipsy Plugin for jQuery - It can be found at http://onehackoranother.com/projects/jquery/tipsy/ and is fairly simple to get started with.

Answer (score 1):

Just set a title on the label:

```
<label for="male" title="Hello This Will Have Some Value">Hello...</label>
```

Using jQuery:

```
<label for="male" data-title="Language" />
<input type="hidden" name="Language" value="Hello This Will Have Some Value">

$("label").prop("title", function() {
    return $("input[name='" + $(this).data("title") + "']").text();
});
```

If you can use CSS3, you can use the `text-overflow: ellipsis;` to handle the ellipsis for you so all you need to do is copy the text from the label into the title attribute using jQuery:

**HTML:**

```
<label for="male">Hello This Will Have Some Value</label>
```

**CSS:**

```
label {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 50px;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

**jQuery:**

```
$("label").prop("title", function() {
   return $(this).text(); 
});
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Xm8Xe/

Finally, if you need robust and cross-browser support, you could use the [DotDotDot jQuery plugin](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/).

Comment: RGraham, Thanks much for your reply. I need to set label value and title dynamically using jquery. Because i get this label value through jquery ajax call. Is it possible to set label title dynamically? Also does ur jquery works for any label? Thanks!

Comment: You can execute any code you wish inside the `.prop` callback demonstrated, but not AJAX as it is asynchronous and prop requires a return value. Instead of prop you could just use .each

Answer (score 1):

Are you find with using standard tooltip? You could use title attribute like

```
<label for="male" title="Hello This Will Have Some Value">Hello...</label>
```

You could add the title attribute of same value to the element that label is for as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you also have jQuery UI, you can add this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(document).tooltip();
});
```

You then need a title instead of a hidden input. RGraham already posted an answer doing this for you :P

Answer (score 0):

You can use the css-property `content` and `attr` to display the content of an attribute in an `:after` pseudo element. You could either use the default title attribute (which is a semantic solution), or create a custom attribute, e.g. `data-title`.

HTML:

```
<label for="male" data-title="Please, refer to Wikipedia!">Male</label>
```

CSS:

```
label[data-title]{
  position: relative;
  &:hover:after{
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: normal;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    left: -8em;
    bottom: 2em;
    content:  attr(data-title);
    background-color: white;
    width: 20em;
    text-aling: center;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tooltips in bootstrap are good, but there is also a very good tooltip function in jQuery UI, which you can read about [here](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/).

Example:

```
<label for="male" id="foo" title="Hello This Will Have Some Value">Hello...</label>
```

Then, assuming you have already referenced jQuery and jQueryUI libraries in your head, add a script element like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).tooltip();
});
</script>
```

This will display the contents of the title attribute as a tooltip when you rollover any element with a title attribute.

Comment: Andy, can i set label title value dynamically, since i get label value through jquery ajax call.